# laravel Get Value of input type text in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to get the value of an input type text to use it for the where clause in my Laravel controller query.

here is a part of the ajax code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
             "url": "{{ route('item_data_table') }}",
             "dataType": "json",
             "type": "POST",
             "data":{ _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"}
        },
        ...
        ...
        ...
    });
});
```

as for my trial, I tried changing:

```
"data":{ _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"}
```

into:

```
"data":{value: $("input[name=categoryname]").val()}
```

Then in my controller, I have this part of query code, Tried it like this:

```
public function dataTable(Request $request)
    {
        $columns = [
            1 => 'id',
            2 => 'item_name',
            3 => 'item_category_name',
            4 => 'item_detail_category_name',
        ];

        $categoryname = Input::get('value');

        $totalData = MItem::count();
        $totalFiltered = $totalData;
        $limit = request()->length;
        $start = request()->start;
        $order = $columns[request()->order[0]['column']];
        $dir = request()->order[0]['dir'];
        $items = MItem::select('m_item.id',
                        'm_item.item_name',
                        'm_item_category.item_category_name',
                        'm_item_detail_category.item_detail_category_name'
                    )
                    ->join('m_item_category', 'm_item.item_category_id', 'm_item_category.id')
                    ->join('m_item_detail_category', 'm_item.item_category_detail_id', 'm_item_detail_category.id');
                    if($categoryname) {
                        $items->where('m_item_category.item_category_name', 'like', '%'.$userID.'%');
                    }
                    $items->offset($start)
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                    ->get();
        $data = [];

...
...
...
}
```

I used `$cateogryname` for my where clause but cannot succesfully do it.

How can be the code done?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to manually pass the token. Just [set up it once](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) and use it for all Ajax calls:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

This will also allow you to not mix PHP with JS.

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass data like this

```
 data: function (d) {
            d.name = $('input[name=name]').val();
            d.email = $('input[name=email]').val();
        }
```

u can find example here
https://datatables.yajrabox.com/collection/custom-filter

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for giving me ideas guys, somehow I did it like this, and got my search function working:

for the ajax code:

```
"ajax":{
         "url": "{{ route('item_data_table') }}",
         "dataType": "json",
         "type": "POST",
         "data":{
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                'item_detail_category_name': $('#item_detail_category_name').val(),
                'item_category_name': $('#item_category_name').val(),
         }
}
```

and for the controller condition,

```
 $limit = request()->length;
        $start = request()->start;
        $order = $columns[request()->order[0]['column']];
        $dir = request()->order[0]['dir'];
        $items = MItem::select('m_item.id',
                        'm_item.item_name',
                        'm_item_category.item_category_name',
                        'm_item_detail_category.item_detail_category_name'
                    )
                    ->join('m_item_category', 'm_item.item_category_id', 'm_item_category.id')
                    ->join('m_item_detail_category', 'm_item.item_category_detail_id', 'm_item_detail_category.id');

        if(request()->item_category_name) {
            $items->where('m_item_category.item_category_name', 'like', '%'.request()->item_category_name.'%');
        }

        if(request()->item_detail_category_name) {
            $items->where('m_item_detail_category.item_detail_category_name', 'like', '%'.request()->item_detail_category_name.'%');
        }

        $totalData = $items->get()->count();
        $totalFiltered = $totalData;

        $data = [];

        $items->offset($start)->limit($limit)->orderBy($order, $dir);

        $items = $items->get();
```